# passing a vector between functions via pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

It was suggested to me to use pointers to add a vector that I wanted to pass from some existing function to another function. I am really stuck on how to get the information back *out* of that pointer though. I've tried a number of things I've read here and there so let me demonstrate what I'm talking about.

primary program:

```
std::vector<float> * dvertex=NULL;

track.calculate(irrelevant stuff, dvertex)
```

secondary program (track, calculate)

```
track::caclulate(irrelevant stuff, vector<float> * dvertex)
{
...
vector<float> pos;
... pos filled after some calculations
if(! (dvertex==NULL))
{
  dvertex = &pos1;
}
```

back to primary, unless I messed up something above, here's some things I've tried

1

```
(*dvertex).at(0)
float z = (*dvertex).at(0)
```

2

```
(*dvertex)[0]
```

and a bunch of stuff that just plain didn't compile. I'm quite stuck as I'm not sure how to get the specific values out of that vector in the main program. I even thought it might be the if(! (dvertex==NULL)) bit, so I changed it to if(dvertex==NULL) but still no joy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***Edit/Update***Thanks so much everyone for the help, but I fear I'm still doing it wrong.

So following the suggestions that I just pass a reference: I did this:

primary

```
std::vector<float> dvertex;
track.calculate( foo, &dvertex);
```

secondary stayed the same (with !Null check)

primary

```
std::cout<<dvertex[0]<<std:endl;
```

(among other attempts to actually use the data)

Thanks a lot for any thoughts on what I'm still doing improperly. Everything compiles, the program just freezes when it gets to a point that the data from dvertex is used.

**Edit:Final fix**

in the secondary program I needed

```
*dvertex = pos1;
```

instead of

```
dvertex = &pos1;
```

Comment: Not to throw more suggestions at you, but you should pass it in as a reference.  Then there's no need to dereference anything, and you get all of the same benefits.

Comment: @jonsca is right, you should do something like track::caclulate(irrelevant stuff, vector<float> & dvertex), then is as simply as treat dvertex as a normal vector and the work made with it will still be available outside the method.

Comment: Sometimes I do like to pass by pointers if the container will be modified.  At the call site that usually requires the use of the address operator: `func(&my_vertor);`  This is a small reminder that the function actually modifies the container.  If you always pass by reference, you can't distinguish between modifying and non-modifying calls without looking at the function declaration.  However, this is purely a matter of style, there is no performance benefit.

Comment: @dappawit: Then the function should be better named. I don't need to look at the signature to know `swap` is going to modify the arguments.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure why these didn't compile for you, because they're valid as long as the pointer is valid and not null:

```
void f(std::vector<int>* v)
{
    if( v != 0 ) {
        int n = (*v)[0];     // ok
        int m = (*v).at(0);  // ok
        int o = v->at(0);    // ok
    }
}
```

But never mind that. Use a reference if you must change the vector, and a const reference if you must not. There's rarely if ever a need to take a container by pointer.

Also, I suggest you check pointers against `0`, not `NULL`, because sometimes `NULL` is defined as `(void*)0` as per C compilers. But some people may argue otherwise here.

Comment: C compilers may define NULL as `(void*)0`, but C compilers ≠ C++ compilers.  A conforming C++ compiler must define NULL as "an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant" (C++03 standard §18.1/4).  Since 0 is also a valid null pointer constant, there is no technical reason to prefer either 0 or NULL—the choice is purely stylistic.  I personally prefer NULL because it explicitly conveys that you are dealing with a pointer, whereas with 0 it's not always clear from context whether you're dealing with an integer or a pointer.

Comment: I prefer the check for NULL it is visually more distinctive (waiting for nullptr)

Comment: @AdamRosenfield If 0 is not implementation defined and `NULL` is, isn't that a technical reason good enough to choose 0 over `NULL`?

Comment: But I really didn't mean to start this argument. I said in my answer that I reckon some will disagree. I just respectfully disagree back.

Answer (score 6):

If you're going to modify the vector, you probably just want to pass it by reference. If you do use a pointer, however, you need to define a vector in main, and then pass the address of that vector:

```
void calculate(std::vector<float> *vertex_array) { 
    vertex_array->pushback(1.0f);
    vertex_array->pushback(2.0f);
}

int main() {    
    std::vector<float> vertexes;
    calculate(&vertexes);

    std::copy(vertexes.begin(), vertexes.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See my note above, but for your scenario to work, you need

```cpp
std::vector<float> * dvertex=NULL;
```

to be

```cpp
std::vector<float> * dvertex = new std::vector<float>();
```